# search autocomplete codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a product database, I am trying search autocomplete, it work perfectly, but I want to display as a link, when I click a search result it will direct to a detail page of that result, I search on google and do as guide but it does not work, check my model, my controller, and my view.

Controller:

```
    function search_auto(){
    $this->load->model('product_model');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
      $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
      $this->product_model->autosearch($q);
    }
  }
```

Model:

```
public function autosearch($q){
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->like('name', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('pbtable');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
         //build an array
      }
      echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
    }
  }
```

View:

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="name"  />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: "search_auto",
    select:function(e,ui) { 
  window.location.href = 'viewpd/' + ui.item.value;
//  console.log(ui.item.the_link);
     }
    })
    });
</script>
```

my detail product page is:

```
http://localhost/ciproject/product/viewpd/ + id product
```

I want, when I type a name to search and click the result it will direct to detail page of that result, but I don't know how to do that, so please help me.

Comment: include the result of your ajax response

Comment: could you tell me more ^^

Comment: You are using ajax to get the results right?? show the response

Comment: tks you, my problem is fixed :D

Comment: So tell how you fixed this in an answer, and mark as solved.